# how to get the name tag of an image

Tags: php, html, image, post, tags

i have an image from my database in a different table displayed as `$draft['draft_image']` and i want to send this data to a different table but im having a problem cause this code doesnt seems to work.. when i tried to click the published button there is no data that is being sent.i use `var_dump` to show the inserted data but nothing shows up in the inspect element.. any idea how can i get the image? this is what's inside my draft_image.. `../images/article/md.png`

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <img data-name="title_image" src="./<?= $draft['draft_image'];?>" style="margin-top:5px;" width="70%" height="55%"><br><br>
<?php
  }
?>
<button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn3 btn-default">Publish</button>
</form>

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $id = $session_id;  
        $file = $_POST['title_image'];

        $ress = $db->draftpublished($id,$file);
        echo $ress;
          }
      ?>
```

Comment: <img> is not form element, that's the way you cannot to send it with POST request

Comment: any idea how to get the data of `$draft['draft_image']` and post it?

Comment: you can use `input type` `hidden` and pass post value

Comment: What do you want to get? The value of `$draft['draft_image']`?

Comment: ohhhh i see.... i was too focus if i can put a name tag on the img i forgot to use the hidden input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the value using hidden type ex:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <img data-name="title_image" src="./<?= $draft['draft_image'];?>" style="margin-top:5px;" width="70%" height="55%"><br><br>
       <input type="hidden" name="imgsrc" value="<?= $draft['draft_image'];?>">
<?php
  }
?>
<button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn3 btn-default">Publish</button>
</form>

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $id = $session_id;  
        $file = $_POST['imgsrc'];

        $ress = $db->draftpublished($id,$file);
        echo $ress;
          }
      ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <!-- added ----------------- -->
 <input type="hidden" name="title_image" value="<?=$draft['draft_image']?>">

   <img data-name="title_image" src="./<?= $draft['draft_image'];?>" style="margin-top:5px;" width="70%" height="55%"><br><br>
<?php
  }
?>
<button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn3 btn-default">Publish</button>
</form>

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $id = $session_id;  
    $file = $_POST['title_image'];

    $ress = $db->draftpublished($id,$file);
    echo $ress;
      }
  ?>
```